# AngularJS: How to create a comment box like Stack Overflow that accepts formatting shortcuts like *sof* for bold

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, markdown

Is there a way achieve the given below shortcuts to format `comments` using AngularJS, jQuery, or JavaScript.

```
**text** or __text__ = Bolding = text
*text* or _text_ = Italics = text
`text` = Code Formatting = text
[example](http://example.com "title") Inline links with title and text
http://example.com plain old links
```

*In case there is a third party tool please suggest only if it is MIT licensed free to be used in any application.*

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: stackoverflow uses pagedown, a fork from showdown: https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Comment: you can use a combination of filters and regex

Comment: I am not familiar with Regular expression but I can work on it to achieve the goal of formatted comments. @MarioCesar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is markdown what you are looking for?

Here are some libs (MIT licensed):

- http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/
- https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js
- https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor

Comment: Do not know why my question is marked down and your answer as well, however, I am going try the `markdown`. I have up voted and accepted your answer. However I lost some points because of some people who don't have a answer but yes they have got a right to downvote for no reason.

Comment: I didn't down-vote but your question is rather broad. My guess is, that is why they down-voted. I can (and I did) suggest some libraries but if you want to write it yourself it's to big to write as an answer. This forum isn't to do the work but to help you with a concrete problem. And asking for libraries is also asking for opinions like "what do you like best..." They don't like that either here :-)

Comment: Downvotes were cast because this question is too broad, contains a recommendation part that is off-topic, and this answer only consists in a set of links to libraries, which encourages posting off-topic questions. Nothing personal here. (By the way, Stack Overflow is not a forum.)